# Will thieves be allowed to regrow their hands?

Tags: quran, punishment

The regeneration medicine is already upon us and it is a matter of time before limbs will be grown within weeks if not days. If we stick to the interpretation that Quran advocates cutting of hands as opposed to a financial hit, then will it still be a an exemplary punishment given the developments in Medicine?

Answer (score -2):

according to [this](https://islamqa.info/en/13926) Islamic Q&A:

> The thief has no right to have the amputated hand reattached, because that means that the signs of the punishment for his crime disappear, and the effectiveness of the rebuke and lesson is lost. It is contrary to the idea of punishment and example as mentioned in the verse in which Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning)

and they base this on:

> [As for] the thief, the male and the female, amputate their hands in recompense for what they committed as a deterrent [punishment] from Allah. And Allah is Exalted in Might and Wise.*[5:38](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=5&verse=38)*

But I don't agree with this as the following [ayat](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=5&verse=39) says:

> But whoever repents after his wrongdoing and reforms, indeed, Allah will turn to him in forgiveness. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.

and every verse begins with the [invocation](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=1&verse=1)

> In the name of Allah, the Beneficent, the Merciful.

Hence, other punishments are preferable when a society can afford it, that is they can be compassionate and merciful towards criminals. Its also a useful observation that when a man is in prison, he has effectively lost the use of his hands for a specified period of time - though we usually just say he's lost his freedom. Of course, if he is put in prison for life, he has effectively lost the use of his hands (and much else) for life.

Comment: I do not see the connection between repentance and lifting of punishment. The [three that stayed behind](https://quran.com/9/118) during the battle of Tabuk truly repented, but they still had to undergo punishment. Please elaborate on your rationale.

Comment: @III-AK-III: the verse quoted is from *Surat At-Tawbah*:'And  [He also forgave] the three who were left behind. [And regretted their error] to the point the earth closed in on them in spite of its vastness and their souls confined them and they were certain their was no refuge in Allah except in Him. Then he turned to them so they could repent. Indeed, Allah is the Accepting of repentence, the Merciful'. This verse seems more about repentence, the acceptance of repentence, and what constitutes mercy than it is about punishment. Indeed, it's about the depth of Allahs mercy.

Comment: @Mozibur Thanks for the answer but I am not talking about the amputated hand reattachment but growing a new one. And how would you prevent that? There is nothing in the relevant verse that would even imply that.

Comment: @david: there is a principle of Islamic thought called [ijtihad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ijtihad) which is concerned with "independent reasoning ... in finding a solution to a legal question ... [which] requires expertise in the Arabic language, theology, revealed texts, and principles of jurisprudence ... [it] is not employed where authentic and authoritative texts (Qur'an and Hadith) are considered unambiguous with regard to the question, or where there is an existing scholarly consensus "; since regenerative medicine is still some way off yet the latter is unlikely to be found.

Comment: @Mozibur Yes I am very familiar with Ijtihad and the official story that goes with it. :) My point, by raising this question is to test the traditional interpretation of the verse in question.

Comment: @David: somehow I don't believe you.

Comment: BTW  regenerative medicine is upon us and part of it is already a reality. In another decade or two it will become routine.

Comment: OK that settles it then :) God bless

Comment: It'd be a good answer if it got rid of everything starting from "But I don't agree with this...", and simply concluded "The same justification would likely apply to hand regrowth."

Comment: @Rebecca J.Stones: you're of course entitled to your opinion; but as I already pointed out the principle of *Ijtihad* allows for interpretation. And to be honest, now that I've reread my answer, I feel I prefer it as it stands.